# Firebase User always initialized to null in oncreate

Tags: android

Firebase user.currentuser() is always null in oncreate. I want to implement this access controll so that only a user called a credit controller can add items to the recyclerview using the floating action button, while other users can only see the items added.
I want the floating action button's visibility to be determined as soon as the activity is open. Is there any other way to achieve this?

I used the reveal button to achieve this but it's a very bad user experience to click it every time you want to go into this activity.
This is my code below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_collections);
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        userEmail = user.getEmail();

        FloatingActionButton buttonAddNote = findViewById(R.id.button_add_note);

        Button revealButton = findViewById(R.id.revealButton);

        revealButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(userEmail.equals("creditcontroller@outlook.com")){
                    buttonAddNote.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    revealButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else revealButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        buttonAddNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CollectionsActivity.this, AddEditNoteActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("USER_EMAIL", userEmail);
                startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_NOTE_REQUEST);
            }
        });
```

Unfortunately I can't upload images yet but the reveal button is just a button that's centered in the activity. Upon clicking it its visibility is set to gone and everything else is set to visible
The code is working but the user experience is pretty bad.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase calls are asynchronous which means that you can't get results instantly.
You should add a callback to your calls.

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
userEmail = user.getEmail();

database.child(userEmail).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String email = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, "email: " + email);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

The code is just an example. It may not work in your case, because you must know the structure of your nodes.
You can read more in the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: Your  answer is very logical, but I can't use it in my case because I'm not using the firebase database. I'm only using the authentication with email and password.

Comment: If I create a fragment and get the result in the onviewcreated will it work? Since onviewcreated is after the fragment is actually created and done. Or is there any kind of wait function that I can use ?

Comment: You can keep the code in onCreate like now. But according to the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users): _The recommended way to get the current user is by calling the getCurrentUser method. If no user is signed in, getCurrentUser returns null_. Are you sure that the user is logged in?